# Are integer literals considered unsigned?

Tags: c, types, numbers

If there is some positive integer literal in my code, say 50, does the compiler consider it as type unsigned int or int?

Comment: you have `U` for unsigned, therefore...

Comment: Thanks a lot for this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A decimal integer literal is of the first type where it can be represented in `int`, `long` or `long long`.

`50` is of type `int`.

unsigned literals can be specified using the `u` or `U` suffix. A decimal integer literal suffixed with `u` or `U` is of the first type where it can be represented in `unsigned int`, `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`.

`50U` is of type `unsigned int`.

Comment: When is a decimal integer literal a long or long long?

Comment: @user2460978: when it's too large to fit in an `int`.

Comment: @user2460978 read my answer again, if it cannot be represented in an `int`.

Comment: C11 §6.4.4.1 5 specifies this in detail.  Interestingly, a _hexadecimal_ constant is the first type that fits in `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`, `long long int`, `unsigned long long int`.

Comment: is it signed or unsigned?

Comment: @SurajJain The answer is: it depends. Decimal unsuffixed integer literals are always signed (starting from C99).